# StyleCop should cancel build. Is this possible?

Tags: msbuild, stylecop

I am planning to use StyleCop in my project. My requirement is that the project should not get compiled when StyleCop returns a warning. Nor debugging should be possible.

I have already integrated StyleCop into MSBuild as described at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/24/source-analysis-msbuild-integration.aspx. It is throwing errors when I build. But, when I start debugging, it is possible (Means, it is possible for programmer to override StyleCop). I can see that the build process is not getting cancelled and all dlls are created.

Is it possible to cancel the build when StyleCop throws errors ?

Thanks,

Madhu

Comment: I'm just a bit curious why you want to do this? I can understand preventing commits to the repository as long as the code doesn't pass StyleCop, but why prevent compiles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to show warnings of StyleCop as errors you can add next line into your *.csproj file:

```
<StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
```

to avoid compiling with stylecop errors you can use StyleCop's target just adding a line into same project file:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\LOCAL_PATH\Microsoft.StyleCop.targets" />
```

After adding this line you will not compile project with StyleCop warnings(errors).

Comment: Yes, Now I marked the answer as accepted. Actually, I am new to this site and is unfamiliar with the etiquettes. Sorry.